# Storing accelerometer data in raspberry pi sd card

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, accelerometer

I am working on a project where my objective is to store acceleration data coming from a motor. For that I am using adafruit mma8451 acceleration sesnsor. Now to store the 3 axis acceleration data, I am using a Raspberry pi. I am trying to store data in a CSV file. Now I need the system to store at least 250 samples per second. Now the problem is, the raspberry pi is storing in one second may be 230 samples, in the next second 210 and in the next one, may be 225. So bascially, the pi is not stable at this speed. If it would store may be 230 samples every second, it would never been a problem. But different number of samples are not accepted, because I need the exact sampling frequency for further analysing the signal.

To check whether this is the problem with storing data in csv file, I tried to see if the pi can print just 250 times "Hello World" or not. It seems, it is unstable if I am using timer using time.sleep() command. Now I would like to show the code I am using for my project

```py
count=0
Path = 0

with open('/home/pi/TrialV10/VibrationsDevice1.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:
    sensorwriter = csv.writer(csvfile) #, delimiter=' ',
                            #quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    sensorwriter.writerow(['Datetime', 'Time', 'X_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Y_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Z_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Count', 'Path'])



    if MotoDetection == 1:
        sensor.MotionSetup()
        while True:
            sensor.Motion()
            time.sleep(0)  
            if sensor.Motion() == True:
                if count==0:
                    TimeStart = time.time()
                    Timer = 0                    
                    pass
                while True: 
                    x, y, z = sensor.acceleration
                    time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                    TimePresent = time.time()
                    Timer = TimePresent - TimeStart
                    X = x #+ Calcx
                    Y = y #+ Calcy
                    Z = z #+ Calcz
                    count = count + 1                  
                    print('DateTime={0}  Time ={1} X={2:0.3f} m/s^2  Y:{3:0.3f} m/s^2  Z:{4:0.3f} m/s^2 count={5}'.format(time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count))
                    sensorwriter.writerow([time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count])
                    time.sleep(0.004) 
                    if Timer > TimingA:
                        exit()
```

Comment: Would be interesting to see how many samples per second can be stored in sqlite on a raspberry pi.

Comment: In addition to the other solutions, I would store the timestamp without formatting to Y-m-d. This way you have the readings with second resolution (possibly you can have microsecond resolution), and be able e.g. to "comb" the samples - if you have 250 one second and 230 another, you can downsample to 230 and 230.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this would be to buffer your sensor readings, and have a separate thread write them to the file in groups. For example:

```
import threading
class FileWriterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,filename,header):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.buffer = []
        self.filename = filename
        self.header = header
    def run(self):
        with open(self.filename,"a+") as f:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
            csvwriter.writerow(self.header)
            while True:
                time.sleep(1) #Wait 1 second between writes to the file.
                writebuffer = []
                while len(self.buffer) > 0: #Clear the current buffer
                    writebuffer.append(self.buffer.pop(0))
                while len(writebuffer) > 0:
                    csvwriter.writerow(writebuffer.pop(0))
    def writerow(self,row):
        self.buffer.append(row)
```

To open the file and start the thread, you would run:

```
sensorwriter = FileWriterThread(filename,header)
sensorwriter.start()
```

To store a row to be written to the file, you would use:

```
sensorwriter.writerow(row)
```

Finally, to stop the thread and save the file, you would use:

```
sensorwriter.cancel()
```

Just remember that you have to create a new thread to re-start it. 
Implemented into your current code, this would result in:

```
import threading
class FileWriterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,filename,header):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.buffer = []
        self.filename = filename
        self.header = header
    def run(self):
        with open(self.filename,"a+") as f:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
            csvwriter.writerow(self.header)
            while True:
                time.sleep(1) #Wait 1 second between writes to the file.
                writebuffer = []
                while len(self.buffer) > 0: #Clear the current buffer
                    writebuffer.append(self.buffer.pop(0))
                while len(writebuffer) > 0:
                    csvwriter.writerow(writebuffer.pop(0))
    def writerow(self,row):
        self.buffer.append(row)

sensorwriter = FileWriterThread('/home/pi/TrialV10/VibrationsDevice1.csv',['Datetime', 'Time', 'X_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Y_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Z_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Count', 'Path'])
sensorwriter.start()

count=0
Path = 0

if MotoDetection == 1:
    sensor.MotionSetup()
    while True:
        sensor.Motion()
        time.sleep(0)  
        if sensor.Motion() == True:
            if count==0:
                TimeStart = time.time()
                Timer = 0                    
                pass
            while True: 
                x, y, z = sensor.acceleration
                time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                TimePresent = time.time()
                Timer = TimePresent - TimeStart
                X = x #+ Calcx
                Y = y #+ Calcy
                Z = z #+ Calcz
                count = count + 1                  
                print('DateTime={0}  Time ={1} X={2:0.3f} m/s^2  Y:{3:0.3f} m/s^2  Z:{4:0.3f} m/s^2 count={5}'.format(time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count))
                sensorwriter.writerow([time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count])
                time.sleep(0.004) 
                if Timer > TimingA:
                    sensorwriter.cancel()
                    exit()
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: It appears the problem is unrelated to the File I/O, and is most likely instead related to the print statement. Printing text to the console is unstable, and is what is actually causing the stability issues. 
Unfortunately, there is no way to make it 100% stable, however you can stabilise it slightly by replacing

```
print('DateTime={0}  Time ={1} X={2:0.3f} m/s^2  Y:{3:0.3f} m/s^2  Z:{4:0.3f} m/s^2 count={5}'.format(time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count))
```

with

```
sys.stdout.write('DateTime={0}  Time ={1} X={2:0.3f} m/s^2  Y:{3:0.3f} m/s^2  Z:{4:0.3f} m/s^2 count={5}\n'.format(time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count))
```

as sys.stdout.write() appears to be more stable than print(). Just remember to import sys at the start of the program. Unfortunately, there will always be some instability, depending on what other tasks the OS is running at the time.

A way to try and maximise stability is to try and limit the sample rate.
Put the code

```
import time
SAMPLERATE = 150 #Number of samples per second.
SAMPLEDELAY = 1/SAMPLERATE
loopwait = 0
```

at the start of your program, and the code

```
while time.time() < loopwait:
    pass
loopwait = time.time()+SAMPLEDELAY
```

as the first instructions in your while True loop.
This makes the final code:

```
import threading,time
class FileWriterThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,filename,header):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.buffer = []
        self.filename = filename
        self.header = header
    def run(self):
        with open(self.filename,"a+") as f:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
            csvwriter.writerow(self.header)
            while True:
                time.sleep(1) #Wait 1 second between writes to the file.
                writebuffer = []
                while len(self.buffer) > 0: #Clear the current buffer
                    writebuffer.append(self.buffer.pop(0))
                while len(writebuffer) > 0:
                    csvwriter.writerow(writebuffer.pop(0))
    def writerow(self,row):
        self.buffer.append(row)

sensorwriter = FileWriterThread('/home/pi/TrialV10/VibrationsDevice1.csv',['Datetime', 'Time', 'X_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Y_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Z_Accel (m/s^2)', 'Count', 'Path'])
sensorwriter.start()

SAMPLERATE = 150 #Number of samples per second
SAMPLEDELAY = 1/SAMPLERATE
loopwait = 0

count=0
Path = 0

if MotoDetection == 1:
    sensor.MotionSetup()
    while True:
        sensor.Motion()
        time.sleep(0)  
        if sensor.Motion() == True:
            if count==0:
                TimeStart = time.time()
                Timer = 0                    
                pass
            while True: 
                while time.time() < loopwait:
                    pass
                loopwait = time.time()+SAMPLEDELAY
                x, y, z = sensor.acceleration
                time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                TimePresent = time.time()
                Timer = TimePresent - TimeStart
                X = x #+ Calcx
                Y = y #+ Calcy
                Z = z #+ Calcz
                count = count + 1                  
                sys.stdout.write('DateTime={0}  Time ={1} X={2:0.3f} m/s^2  Y:{3:0.3f} m/s^2  Z:{4:0.3f} m/s^2 count={5}\n'.format(time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count))
                sensorwriter.writerow([time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z, count])
                time.sleep(0.004) 
                if Timer > TimingA:
                    sensorwriter.cancel()
                    exit()
```

Unfortunately, there isn't really a way to ensure a consistent measurement rate, however this code should help make it more consistent than before.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your effort and time. I have tried your code. But I am getting the following error
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/New/LuigisCodeV10.py", line 91, in <module>
    sensorwriter.start()
RuntimeError: thread.__init__() not called
I am not that expert in python although I have understood what is going inside the code. Would like to request you to take a look if possible.

Comment: Solved the problem by adding the line 
super(FileWriterThread, self).__init__()
in the definition of the thread.
But its giving the same problem with the result. Its still not stable.

Comment: @AnkitChanda Unfortunately there is no way to guarantee exact stability, however I have managed to update the answer with a way (I hope) to stabilise it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried the new code. But the instability is still there. I think the reason is because the value of the timer goes till  16 decimal point. For example 
Time =0.9906363487243652 has been printed. i.e the resolution is not milisecond one. If we can change the implementation of the time.time() function, I think it would be better.

Comment: Just to simplify everything, 
If you try to print "hello world" for one second with the same time of sleep, you will see that once it will print 200 times, the next time it will print 220 times. 
So I dont think its a problem with the storing of the file, rather its about how we are implementing the timer.

Answer (score 1):

Store the data with an internal buffer and flush the buffer if you reach your sample count and write the data into your CSV file.
Here is an example (untested):

```
Buffer = list()
Count = 0

if(MotoDetection == 1):
    sensor.MotionSetup()
    while True:
        sensor.Motion()
        if(sensor.Motion() == True):
            if(count == 0):
                TimeStart = time.time()
                Timer = 0
            else: 
                x, y, z = sensor.acceleration
                time_now = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                TimePresent = time.time()
                Timer = TimePresent - TimeStart
                X = x #+ Calcx
                Y = y #+ Calcy
                Z = z #+ Calcz
                count = count + 1

                Buffer.append([time_now, Timer, X, Y, Z])

                time.sleep(0.004)

                if(len(Buffer) == 230):

                    del Buffer

                    # Save the buffer
                    with open('/home/pi/TrialV10/VibrationsDevice1.csv', 'a+') as csvfile:
                        for Entry in Buffer:
                            csvfile.write(str(Entry) + ";")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and help. I have tried the code given by you. But its not working. I am having the same trouble.

Comment: In the answer above you say, that you think that the timer is the problem. So maybe a Raspberry Pi (with an OS and python) isn´t the right choice for this task, because the Raspbian OS isn´t a real-time OS and the sleep command isn´t that accurate at all. Maybe a small Arduino Microcontroller with an SD card or an C application which uses the system timer is the better solution.

Comment: To be honest; I have implemented the program on another device (Bosch XDK ) where its working properly. But I really wanted to know if there is a solution to this problem in raspberry pi. May be there is not any like you said.